# LINQ Expressions throwing VerificationException

Tags: c#, clr, linq-expressions

Why does this code throw "*System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.*"?

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(TypedReference).GetMethod("InternalMakeTypedReference", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IntPtr));
ParameterExpression p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
ParameterExpression p3 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IntPtr[]));
ParameterExpression p4 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Type));
Expression exp = Expression.Call(mi, Expression.Convert(p1, typeof(void*)), p2, p3, Expression.Convert(p4, Types.RuntimeType));
var m = Expression.Lambda<Action<IntPtr,object,IntPtr[],Type>>(exp, p1, p2, p3, p4).Compile();
m(IntPtr.Zero,null,null,null);
```

The exception isn't thrown due to wrong arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot build Expression trees containing unsafe code. Unsafe code means that type/memory safety cannot be verified, but according to [this error description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546089%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Expressions can only be compiled if their code is verifiable.

It should be fine to just pass around `IntPtr` in the expression tree but that wouldn't help if the argument is `void*`.

A viable way might be using [`Reflection.Emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate the method access IL directly. It cannot by default call a private method but here's an answer for solving that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1778446/1659828

Anyway in your case I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but trying to use an implementation detail of non-CLS-compliant API seems like there might be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the DynamicMethod solution.